# Convert \n to <br /> but if it doesn't follow <h2> or [h2]

Tags: c#, regex, bbcode

I want to replace \n with <br /> in a string. But not that simple. There shouldn't be a </h2> or [/h2] before `\n` if it is to be raplaced.

For example put a <br /> between "Something" and "Another thing" in this example:

```
Something
Another thing
```

But do nothing in this example:

```
<h2>Something</h2>
<p>Another thing</p>
```

I come up with `(?<!\]|\>)\n` working on [this](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) .NET Regex Tester. Something to be replaced is found in the first example but not in the second as expected. However, I couldn't make this nice regex work like this in my C# code. The following code replaces all `\n`s regardless whether it follows a `</h2>` or not.

```
Cevrilen = Regex.Replace(Cevrilen, @"(?<!\]|\>)\n", "<br />");
```

How can I replace breaks just if they are not followed by a `</h2>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<!(?:<\/h2>|\[\/h2\]))\n
```

That should do it (using a negative look-behind to disqualify `</h2>` or `[/h2]` preceding a `\n`)

Comment: This also replaces `\n` although there is a `</h2>` before it: `Cevrilen = Regex.Replace(Cevrilen, @"(?<!(?:<\/h2>|\[\/h2\]))\n", "<br />");`

Comment: I solved the problem by changing `(?<!(?:<\/h2>|\[\/h2\]))\n` to `(?<!(?:<\/h2>|\[\/h2\]))\r\n`. Besides `(?<!\]|\>)\r\n` also work when `\r` is added. There had been `\r` between `</h2>` and `\n`.

Comment: @sevenkul: You may want to class it to `[\r\n]+` so it matches `\n`, `\r\n`, `\n\r`. But, keep in mind it will turn `\n\n` into a **single** `<br />`, too. Alternatively you can use `(\r?\n)` and match `\n` or `\r\n` a single time.

Answer (score 0):

If your html complies with xhtml, then load it as System.Xml.Linq.XDocument and do not try to analyze it with Regex. As some said, "Not even Chuck Norris can do that".

Comment: Indeed. "Tony The Pony, He Comes."

Comment: I am reading the string from a pure txt file. There are just two lines like in the examples in the question.

Comment: So, isn't it possible to do this simple operation?

Comment: You can try your luck with Regex, but html has a recursive structure (tags can be nested) and regex cannot cope with that.